# How can fix Timeout Error - The preview took too long to load. for preview layout in Android Studio Iguana | 2023.2.1 Canary 6?

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, timeout

In **Android Studio Iguana | 2023.2.1 Canary 6** , When I use this version of Android studio, It cannot preview any layout while I use older version such as *Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 2 *with the same layout , there isn't any problem.

```
Timeout Error
The preview took too long to load. The issue can be caused by long operations or infinite loops on the Preview code. 
If you think this issue is not caused by your code, you can report a bug in our issue tracker.
```

[image]

I already,

1- Increased Memory for android studio from 2048 to 4G

2- Used different Graphics performance in Windows 11

3- Cleaned Caches by Invalidate Caches

4- Report this bug to https://issuetracker.google.com/